# No CP Theme after upgrade to EE 2x

Tags: ee2-upgrades, cp-themes

After upgrading from EE 1.8 to EE2, my CP theme no longer works. I double-checked paths, I tried moving my cp_themes folder to the system folder. No luck. Any thoughts?

Comment: Grasping at straws, but could there be a permissions issue with your themes folder? Unlikely, but it's worth checking.

Answer (score 1):

This is a path issue. That's the only reason a theme goes away. I suggest rechecking all the paths and moving your cp_themes folder back to where its original location. One of the paths is wrong.

Comment: I double-checked and everything is correct. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Check the page source and check what is being used for the js/css file URLs. Are those correct? Are the files opening if you paste into browser?

Answer (score 0):

My site was residing on a sub-domain. However, when copying the files and directories from the live site an .htaccess rule was forcing www on my subdomain (www.dev.domain.com vs dev.domain.com). Solved! Thanks for your help

Comment: I always use a relative URL for the theme folder url in my `config.php`: `$config['theme_folder_url']= '/themes/';`